# Car rental in Italy with license held less than one year

Tags: driving, italy, driving-licenses

I am traveling to Italy in 6 weeks and would like to rent a car.

I passed my driving license in Norway in November last year, all rental companies I have contacted require you to have held your license for a minimum of one year before renting a car.

Is this a legal requirement?

Answer (score 1):

All the Italian companies I've checked requires the driver to be at least 21 years old and a driving license held for at least an year, claiming that the second one is a European requisite. Problem is, I can't find the exact law anywhere.

But given my long personal experience with renting car, I can tell you that if all the major companies are doing it then they all must have a good reason to do it.

---

I made some more research, and I cannot find anywhere the normative that rental companies are referring to; mostly because the just say (when they say it) that it's a European thing without any reference at all.

But I've found a possible explanation: there are many limits in place for drivers younger than 21 years old and/or with a driver license held from less than a year, at least in Italy (I found the law reference in their Driving Code). Basically if you fall into those two categories you need a special (more expensive) insurance and can drive only de-powered cars (plus other small tibidids).

That would make really complicate for rental companies to rent cars, because they would have to keep some car only for young and/or new drivers, with a more expensive insurance and a different engine. Now, I don't know if this applies to the entire Europe or not, and in which way...

Comment: E.g. Sixt operates with very different regulations in different European (EU?) countries. In Austria and Germany, you must have held your driver's license for at least one day. In France it is two years and in Spain three years. There is obviously no EU wide regulation on this subject.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo so, the moment European rental companies affirm that they are all following an European normative that requires a minimum held license, your argument to disprove them is by listing that they all requires a minimum held license? Quite a logic you have, man!

Comment: I agree with Tor-Einar, I have seen different regulations for different countries. I am wondering specifically about Italy. I have also read in several places that a surcharge can be paid to bypass some of these requirements.

Comment: Not sure how reliable this link is, but according to http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/vehicles/cars/car-rental-abroad/index_en.htm there is no EU Wide regulations regarding Car Hire.

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose I know, I'm having really hard times finding it too, but as Tor-Einar pointed out it's a European wide thing, so it makes no sense that it doesn't come from a common legislation or something like that. But I've found something, let me update the answer

Comment: I think you misread Tor-Einars comment, he says there is clearly NO EU wide regulation. I look forward to your updated answer :)

Comment: Your edit does explain it a bit. I will continue to contact rental car companies and hope for the best. Worst case scenario we hire with my wife's license and try to add me as an additional driver hoping they dont notice :) Thank you

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose let's suppose that the rental company do not notice, and you safely drive away from their site with your just rented car. Now, maybe you could be stopped by a policeman: he'll take him just a minute to notice that and, being Italian, will probably have some problems expressing himself in English. You'll be unable to explain yourself, he will be forced to bring you to the central station, you'll get fined, you'll get your licensed retired, you'll get a complaint from the rental company, and you'll either need to spend a lot of money to go back to Italy for the trial

Comment: or to spend a lot of money for someone to do it for you and in the immediate you'll have f**ed up your holiday.

But, let's suppose for a moment that you are not used to drive in Italy, what about the second scenario where you hit a pedestrian, no one luckily get hurt, and you end up in huge legal mess for the following few years and stripped to the bone of all your money?

Comment: Why would the policemen fine him? For being a new driver? For driving without the rental company's permission? Both are civil violations that are settled in court, not by traffic police.

Comment: Both are the responsibility of the rental company. As a driver I am to ensure I have proper paperwork (my license and my car rental agreement) both of which I will have.

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose "As a driver I am to ensure I have proper paperwork..." please add "with respect to the legislation of the country in which I am going to drive" - and things get fuzzy there. And you can't just offload the responsibility of knowing the local rules to the rental company.

Comment: No. My responsibility is to ensure I am legally entitled to drive. I hold a full EU driving license, therefore I am fully entitled to drive almost anywhere in the world. I also need to ensure I have valid insurance, when I rent a car from a car hire firm that car is rented with full insurance. If there is a clause which means I am not entitled to drive the car then it is the rental companies responsibility to ensure they do not rent the car to me.